# How to get selected value of dropdownlist in edititemtemplate - datagridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I've created a DropDownList in a DataGrid EditItemTemplate. (Manually)

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="nazwa" DataValueField="nazwa" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("nazwa") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:baza_pismConnectionString1 %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [nazwa] FROM [podmioty]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

how can I get the selected value from the dropdownlist in the code behind?

Comment: when u want the selected value of drop down i mean at which event

Comment: Try looking at the CommandName and CommandArgument attributes for the DropDownList, and the OnRowCommand attribute/event for the GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to find the value of dropdown during editing, this code will do

```
    protected void gridview1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
GridViewRow row = gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            DropDownList ddl = row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
        var value=ddl.SelectedValue;
            //now do whatever with that value
        }
```

Comment: I have error. The name "row" does not exisit in current context.